# オプティマイズリー (Optimizely A/B テスト)でのReact.jsの記述

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ターゲットにしたいページが、React.jsで動いている為　JQueryやVanila JS での記述ではなく全てReact での記載でエレメントを書き換えたいと考えております。今まで、cssとjQueryでの記載しかしたことがなく、React.jsで全て動いているページをターゲットにしてオプティマイズリー上で上書きしたくてもできません。HTMLの削除、css追加なども全く効かない状態です。

まだオプティマイズリーの初心者でどのようにReact jsをオプティマイズリー上で記載していいのかがわかりません。どなたかOptimizely Xでのリアクトのサンプルのようなコードを例としてあげていただけないでしょうか？